# Faileed to create Context 0x30005 android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I tried to run the first android app "HelloWorld" I receive this error:

```
[2014-01-26 12:57:31 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2014-01-26 12:57:31 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2014-01-26 12:57:42 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-01-26 12:57:42 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-01-26 12:59:09 - HelloWorld] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Same error from Eclipse and from command line.

I have the following configuration:
laptop ACER Aspire 5315, Vista Ultimate SP2
JDK 7
Eclipse Kepler

I created the avd with the following values: 512RAM, SD card 128. I tried some other values for avd. The same error appear.
I searched from Internet to the answer and I tried everything what I found: reinstalling everything, installing the driver for video card.

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to **AVD Manager**, Select created AVD & then Edit. Check the box **Use Host GPU**. It worked for me.